# PHPDoc using @method to declare magic method and @see to pick documentation from another method

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc, magic-methods

What I want is that when I declare a magic method with `@method` PHPDoc, can i use `@see` so that the magic method has the same PHPDoc as the method pointed via `@see`

Here is the code of what I have tried. But IDE did not recognize it. I am using Netbeans 7.3.1.

```
/**
* @method string my_method() @see _my_method()
*/
class Foo {
  public __call($name, $args) {
     $name = "_".$name;
     $this->$name($args);
  }

  /**
  * @return String
  */
  protected _my_method() {
     return "bar";
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify "did not work" (what *did* happen?)

Comment: Have updated the question, does that explain better?

Answer (score 1):

The exact parsing will depend on which IDE you're using, but [the PHPDocumentor documentation for `@see`](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/see.html) shows a couple of differences from your usage:

- The `@see` tag is on its own line, not appended to the line before. [`@link`](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/link.html) has a separate "inline" syntax if you want to include a cross-reference inside a description (`{@link http://example.com/my/bar}`).
- The "target" should be a fully qualified element name, not just the local method name, e.g. `@see Foo::_my_method()`

There is also a [draft PSR](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#816-see) to standardise the behaviour, with similar requirements.

Comment: Ya such usage of @see works fine with normal functions but not with magic methods

Comment: This looks promising: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#54-inline-phpdoc

Answer (score 0):

I would like to create links to "other" methods to, and I tried `@see`, `@link` and lots of other stuff, without any helpfull results.

In phpstorm everything is yust displayed as text.

**BUT:**

I discovered, that you can write own html-code, so
e.g.

```php
/**
* @method string my_method() see <a href="http://my-documentation/my_method()">_my_method()</a>
*/
class Foo {
}
```

would work to create links on external pages.
Unfortunally it only works for external links, and not for links to methods in your editor.